# Error: Cannot Find Symbol on Java; how to declare arrays

Tags: java

I am new to Java and do not know how to set an array. My reset method cannot access myList when I later call it in the main method...

```
public Hand(){
  ArrayList<Object> myList=new ArrayList<>();
 }

 public void reset(){
  myList.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your constructor you are simply creating an `ArrayList` object that passes out of scope. You need to declare it as a class variable. Try something like:

```
 ArrayList<Object> myList;
 public Hand(){
    myList=new ArrayList<>();
 }

 public void reset(){
    myList.clear();
 }
```

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for more information.